# App Store rejection: Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

My app is rejected with the following message i don't fully understand, because there is a login and it is not Apple related. I provided the login in Resolution Center.

---

Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

Specifically, we were still unable to Sign up or Sign in with Apple. Please review the details below and complete the next steps.

Review device details:

- Device type: iPhone and iPad
- OS version: iOS 14.4

Next Steps

Please run your app on a device to reproduce the issues, then revise and submit your app for review.

If at first you're unable to reproduce the issue, try the following:

- For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce.
- For app updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version, then follow the steps to reproduce.

If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these features were intended to work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because App Store rejection issues are off topic

Comment: Why ? This is something technical and tricky, and sharing experiences would help. Else, i wonder what other place than SO is suitable for this (perhaps a specific section but all AppStore rejections are standing in SO right now).

Comment: Do you have any other social logins enabled in your app?  Facebook? Google?

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you for your reply. No, i have not. I have resubmitted and asking Apple to point me what is wrong.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear in the wording, they can't sign in or sign up. You say you provided login credentials at resolution stage, but, are you 100% sure they work? Have you tested them on a clean device? Also even if your provided login works does the sign up side of things work? If not, they will reject the app.

Comment: @latenitecoder this is certainly a signup with apple that i don't understand exactly. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Graveen They pointed out "unable to sign-in/ sign-up with apple". As you have already mentioned that u have not implemented any social login, so u need to make sure the test credentials work for sign-in and similarly the sign-up process should also be completed. If all is good, then, just reply back as they have instructed. Also, they have mentioned the device and OS details, make sure that this feature works there.

Comment: @Graveen I am inclined towards voting to close, but I haven't yet. Can you please update your question, _**because there is insufficient information for us to help you.**_  We need more details about your project and your submission, not just copy pasting the rejection notice.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: The tags are app-store and app-store connect and it's closed because the "question does not appear to be about programming". It would seem to me that the TAGS themselves do not appear to be about programming, that's where your real problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you multiple options to debug and solve this problem:

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651533?page=8 There is an issue with 14.4 and xcode 12 related to apple login. You can try with iOS 13 and submit video at resolution centre.
- Is it due to two factor authentication ? Cross-check apple ID settings.
- Try changing http to https on web server, if applicable.

Let us know which option was useful to you.

Comment: It was the first, an issue with 14.4. I finally disabled "Sign in with Apple".

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Apple believes there is a social login (Google, Facebook, etc) included in your app. You're going to need to ensure there's not.

You've already mentioned that there's not - but perhaps there is some package you're using which includes code that triggers some automated flagging process? Review your third party dependencies.

The best thing you can do though is get more specificity from Apple. They will usually clarify rejection notices if you contact them with questions.